# On which beats should a composer avoid consecutive perfect intervals?

Tags: counterpoint

In an exercise in a grade 5 textbook, I am asked to write a bassline to a given melody. I am told to avoid consecutive parallel intervals but I am not told if that means on beat 1 of each bar or on each beat of each bar. So in 4/4 or 3/4 should I avoid the consecutives on beat one of each bar or should each beat avoid consecutives? Similarly, in 6/8 would a P5 on beat 1 and a P8 on beat 4 be something to avoid or is it just between beat 1s on consecutive bars?

Comment: I suppose you mean parallel 5ths and octaves but you didn't say. According to your post you were not told that there should be exceptions, so if you are told to avoid consecutive parallel intervals you should avoid them with no exceptions.

Comment: I understand but how many intervening notes do there have to be for it to not be parallels? An 8th note between two parallels are obviously not enough according to the reply below.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be referencing consecutive parallel intervals on the beats *with intervening intervals on the offbeats* (what some call "strong-beat parallels"). For example:

[image]

We look at the string of intervals here— 5, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 3—and we may think we're in the clear since there are no consecutive 5ths or 8ths.

But the motion from beat 1 to beat 2 strongly implies parallel fifths, just as the motion from beat 3 to beat 4 strongly implies parallel octaves. Even though the parallels are briefly broken up by an intervening arpeggiation in one of the voices, our ears still tend to hear the parallel motion on the beats.

*This is typically viewed an unstylistic no matter what beats they occur on.* Tempo, however, can add to the difficulty; if our 4/4 example is suddenly at 200bpm, we might even want to consider parallels from beat 1 to beat 3, or from beat 3 back to beat 1, just because the tempo is so fast that now beats 1 and 3 start to feel like a larger beat 1 to beat 2.

The same logic applies to the 6/8 that you mention: with a fast enough tempo, you'll want to prevent these parallels between the first and fourth eighth notes of the measure, too.

Comment: ok so the 8th notes dont break up the parallels on the 4 strong beats but what about if there were parallels on beat 1 and 3 only? or what about if there were only parallels on beat 1 and 1 of the next bar? are all those ok?

Comment: I would argue that it's ultimately a question of tempo. So if these are typical "four-part chorales" in a music theory textbook, they're slow enough that you can safely assume that parallels from beats 1 to 3 (or from 1 to 1) are not problematic.

Comment: well then the text book should say that. How on earth could someone guess at which point the consecutive perfect intervals become problematic... Don't you agree? Unless maybe that is too complicated for grade 5... anyhow, you cant bake a cake without the ingredients

Comment: @armani Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the ABRSM texts (which I'm assuming you use?), so I can't speak to the textbook efficacy. It could certainly be made clear, but it's possible that they're only giving you examples where you question won't cause any problems. (But I agree, they should still make it clear for enthusiastic students like yourself!)

Comment: I am doing Trinity but I also do the ABRSM . I wish the answer was more decisive but it seems like it really depends on various factors.

Answer (score 1):

At least when I learned counterpoint (and when people on Musescore evaluate counterpoint and leave behind comments on scores), **all beats should avoid consecutive parallel 5ths and octaves**. In practice, both of these parallel intervals stick out like a sore thumb to me *on first listen* because of their rarity. Check your work thoroughly to always avoid these consecutive intervals.

Comment: yeah ok I kind of figured this but at which point is it ok to have the parallels? between beat 1 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a bit to @Richard's answer.

You can try thinking in terms of *harmonic rhythm* not just beats.

If the harmonic rhythm were slow, like two beats per chord, then your potential parallels would be two *beats* apart, but not two *chords* apart. It's like the arpeggiation/beat subdivision thing in Richard's example, but on the rhythmic level higher than the beat.

Comment: there seems to be a lot of speculation here... number of chords, harmonic rhythm, tempo.  There doesnt seem to be a clear cut answer it seems. So wouldnt it be easier to say, chord to chord is considered a consecutive parallel while a chord that is two chords away is ok?

Comment: by the way... in my exercise there are no chords... just melody notes.. so it is a 2 part writing exercise.

Comment: 3 note makes a chord is just a basic definition. But chords are just theoretical concepts. If the style is harmonic, homophonic you get chords (incomplete) from 2 parts, and even 1 part can imply chords. In _all_ of those various forms of completeness good voice leading should be observed. Look at examples like Bach's solo cello suites.

Comment: "...wouldnt it be easier to say, chord to chord..." yes, but you framed the question by "beats" so the answers try to tease apart the implications of beats instead of chords.

Comment: yes I understand but with two voices who is to say which are passing notes?

Comment: that's the point about "chord are theoretical", they must be identified, essentially that is harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

All of them.  That is, unless you're NOT writing in Bach chorale style, in which case they're fine.